# Swift: Unknown attribute 'Observable'

Tags: swift, xcode15

In Xcode 15 (still beta) with `Swift 5.9`, I want to use `@Observable` instead of

```
@Observable struct Feature {
    let name: String
}
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
Unknown attribute 'Observable'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to import `Observation` framework

```
import Observation
```

Comment: or `import SwiftData`